# How to make query both to parent and child index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I got parent index `users` and child `purchase`. Purchase has field `purchase_count` it is number of purchase made by user, for example first purchase of some user will be with `purchase_count` = 1, second with 2 etc.
I want to make query to get total number of users, number of users who had first purchase, number of users who had second etc. For example `All: 100, 1: 10, 2: 6, 3: 3 etc.`.
I know how to do it in two requests, first get count of all users next term aggregation of purchases based on `purchase_count` field, but can I do it somehow in single query?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a datatype in Elasticsearch called parent-join or parent-child previously: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html
2. That datatype needs to be in a single index. There are no joins across indices in Elasticsearch.

You probably want to look into parent-join for your usecase, but you'll have to restructure your data to reside in a single index.